# German nouns gender source

Tags: data-request, language, programming, database, dictionary

I want to create some sort of spell checking program for German language, for which i need a database with all the words and their gender description(only their gender description) to cross reference every word.

Can anyone help me to find such database to download? i would like if it would be in rows and columns so i can later then import it into a sql database in order to use it more easily

I want to create some sort of spell checking program for German language, for which I need a database with all the words and their gender description(only their gender description) to cross reference every word.

Can anyone help me to find such database to download?

I would like if it would be in rows and columns so I can later then import it into a sql database in order to use it more easily

Answer (score 1):

The German language has 3 genders for nouns: Masculine, Feminine, Neutral. Unlike English which has one article "The", German has many articles change based on the grammatical case. Nominativ, Akkusativ, Dativ, Genitiv! ... It's a long story :D

You can read more about [German nouns here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_nouns)

Anyway, in German, this is not the best way to determine the noun gender, there are other rules that make it easy to guess.

Dict.cc version (About 334,000 words): You can download data set from [dict.cc](https://www1.dict.cc/translation_file_request.php?l=e), you can find more information about this data set on the following URL:

- http://www1.dict.cc/translation_file_request.php

[Wiktionary.org](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/dewiktionary/latest/dewiktionary-latest-pages-meta-current.xml.bz2) version (About 50,000 words): Get data set from the following URL:

- http://dumps.wikimedia.org/dewiktionary/latest/dewiktionary-latest-pages-meta-current.xml.bz2

**Few additional Resources**

- [Analyzer of German nouns gender](https://github.com/aabouzaid/german-nouns-gender-analyzer)
- [german nouns: gender analysis](https://www.kaggle.com/fkdplc/german-nouns-gender-analysis)

Comment: yeah.. frankly I speak German and that's the reason why I wanted this kind of database, I just needed to have their gender in nominativ only and later on working on perfecting the program. Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you have any smaller/simpler resource? Because for speed rate purposes I see this file has a lot of unnecessary  and a file with only the noun + gender would be much more preferable

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the R language, then you could try to use the `hunspell` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hunspell/vignettes/intro.html

Since it is open-source, maybe you can extract the data you want for your project.

Comment: I'm not using R language